# WinRT - Loading data while keeping the UI responsive

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing a Windows Metro app, and am getting an issue with the UI becoming unresponsive.  As far as I can tell, the cause is as follows:

```
    <ListView
...
        SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged"            
...
```

This event is handled here:

```
    async void ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation()) this.InvalidateVisualState();

        MyDataItem dataItem = e.AddedItems[0] as MyDataItem;
        await LoadMyPage(dataItem);
    }

    private async Task LoadMyPage(MyDataItem dataItem)
    {            
        SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
        SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri(FEED_URI));                    

        string html = ConvertRSSToHtml(feed)
        myWebView.NavigateToString(html, true);            
    }
```

`LoadMyPage` takes a while to complete, as it gets data from a web service and loads it onto the screen.  However, it looks like the UI is waiting for it: my guess is that until the above event completes.

So my question is: what can I do about this?  Is there a better event I can hook into, or is there another way to handle this?  I thought about starting a background task, but that seems like overkill to me.

EDIT:

Just to clarify the scale of this problem, I'm talking about a maximum of 3 - 4 seconds unresponsive.  This is by no means a long running job.

EDIT:

I've tried some of the suggestion below, however, the entire call stack from the `SelectionChanged` function is using async/await.  I've tracked it down to this statement:

```
myFeed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri);
```

Which doesn't seem to be continuing processing until it's complete.

EDIT:

I realise this is turning into War & Peace, but below is a replication of the problem using a blank metro app and a button:

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Width="200" Height="200">test</Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="test"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = null;

        SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
        Uri feedUri = new Uri(myUri);

        try
        {
            feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);

            foreach (var item in feed.Items)
            {       
                test.Text += item.Summary.Text + Environment.NewLine;                    
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            test.Text += "Connection failed\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Unresponsive"? If you place a button on the page and try to mouse over, do you see the mouse over behavior? Can you interact with the page at all? Are you trying to transition the page during LoadPage? If the RetrieveFeedAsync method takes awhile to complete, it will not lock the UI, but it will seem as if nothing is happening.

Comment: The controls on the screen do not respond.  The mouse moves, but the UI of the app is temporarily not usable.

Comment: How many items are in the returned feed?

Comment: In the example above, there's 50... but I get the same behaviour if I remove the `foreach` loop altogether

Comment: I can't see the code for LoadMyPage anywhere... please include that. Ideally, please strip this down to a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I've updated the code to include LoadMyPage, but the program at the bottom is basically a stripped down replication - just a button and a call to `RetrieveFeedAsync`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
SyndicationFeed feed = null;

SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();

var feedUri = new Uri(myUri);

try {
    var task = client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri).AsTask();

    task.ContinueWith((x) => {
        var result = x.Result;

        Parallel.ForEach(result.Items, item => {
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                test.Text += item.Title.Text;
            });
       });     
   });
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

I tried it on my machine by adding a button to an app using the Grid app template.  I could scroll the grid of items back and forth while I updated the title of the page without problem.  Though I didn't have a lot of items to it went really fast so it was tough to be 100% positive.

Comment: This works (I left our the Parallel `ForEach`) - thanks.  I was under the impression that `await` effectively did the same as this - so what does this do that `await` doesn't?

Comment: When you use await, the compiler will automatically marshal the code that follows the completion of the async call back onto the UI thread.  Tasks are used in the background to accomplish this, but the compiler magic moves the opportunity for background processing back onto the main thread.  In my code, we take control of the task explicitly and use it to continue with work on its own thread instead of going back to the UI thread.  Depending on how much data your looping through and how you want the UI to update, you may want to stick with the Parallel.ForEach

Comment: You're leaking exceptions there, aren't you? The task is quick to start and the continuation is not in the same synchronization context that you have exception handling on.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using `await` in front of `LoadMyPage` I am assuming that it compiles and that it returns a `Task`. Given that, I've created a little example.

Let us assume that `LoadMyPage`(and `Sleep()`) looks like this:

```
public Task<string> LoadMyPage()
{
    return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                {
                                                    Sleep(3000);
                                                    return "Hello world";
                                                });
}
static void Sleep(int ms)
{
    new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(ms);
}
```

And that the `XAML` looks like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Result" />
    <ListView x:Name="MyList" SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListViewItem>Test</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Test2</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
    <Button>Some Button</Button>
    <Button>Some Button2</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

We can then have the `SelectionChanged` event handler looking like this:

```
private async void ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                                 SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyList.IsEnabled = false;
    var result = await LoadMyPage();

    Result.Text = result;

    MyList.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

The `Task` that `LoadMyPage` returns will run in parallel which means that when that task is running, the `UI` should not freeze. Now to get the result from that `Task` you use `await`. This will create a continuation block.

So in this example, when you select something, the `ListView` is disabled for the entire loading time and then re-enabled once the `Task` has finished. You can verify that the UI didn't freeze up by pressing the buttons to see that it is still responsive.

If `LoadMyPage` interacts with the UI, you need to re-arrange it a little bit, have it return a `ViewModel` or the result that you want and then put everything together again on the UI thread.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because I'm using the asynchronous method `RetrieveFeedAsync`

Comment: -1: the question is about async, not about long running items and you can't sleep in WinRT.

Comment: @Henrik, Read my answer and check the code samples again. I'm simulating `Sleep` by using `ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(ms)`. I don't see how my answer is not about `async`, could you please clearify?

Comment: @Henrik, No? The `Task` runs asynchronously and is `awaited` in `ItemListView_SelectionChanged`.

Comment: But a WaitOne on a reset event is not an asynchronous operation. I think you are mixing up two concepts; concurrency and async. You are assuming there's a thread pool that runs the tasks that you can block a thread on, and then you are not doing it async. Perhaps my fish with your answer is that the example is of 'sleep' instead of adressing the issue that the GUI should be responsive. And when you await in the GUI synchronization context, you are creating the same unresponsive behaviour that the OP wants to get rid of. Instead, do a SynchronizationContext.Post to GUI when done.

Comment: @Henrik, I think you are reading way too much into it. I'm just using it to simulate that something is locking up in the background that I want to wait for and still have a responsive UI. I'm getting the desired result on my machine, it doesn't lock up the UI for me and continues at the continuation block when the sleep has passed.

Comment: I might, but I think this is related to something else than postponing the execution with a callback - there's something missing -- what if you were doing CPU-intensive work -- e.g. parsing a lot of XML from a feed that loaded from a HDD cache, like in the OP example - would that be done concurrently or would it lag the UI thread?

Comment: The reason I came to this thread is that I have the same problem but I'm using asynch throughout everything, so there's something more to it.

Comment: It should of course be done concurrently; not locking up the UI thread.

Comment: So how would you know what synchronization context it's run on? Are AsyncInfo.Run .. on another context? Task.Factory.CreateNew? But not when letting the compiler return a Task from your methods? WHy is that not the case?

Comment: @Henrik, I think it's much easier if we take this somewhere else than in the comments. Hop on JabbR and we can continue there.

Answer (score 2):

A background thread is most definitely *not* overkill. That's precisely how you handle this kind of problem.

Don't perform lengthy tasks on the UI thread, or you will tie up the UI and cause it to become unresponsive. Run these on a background thread, and then have that thread raise an event that can be processed by the main UI thread when it finishes.

Showing some kind of progress indicator on the UI thread is also useful. Users like to know that *something is happening*. That will reassure them that the app isn't broken or frozen, and they'll be willing to wait a bit longer. This is why all web browsers have some kind of "throbber" or other loading indicator.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that `LoadMyPage` is doing something synchronously. Remember, `async` doesn't run your code on a background thread; by default all of its actual *code* will be run on the UI thread (see the [async/await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) or my [async/await intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)). So, if you block in an asynchronous method, it's still blocking the calling thread.

Take a look at `LoadMyPage`. Is it using `await` to call the web service? Is it doing expensive processing of the data before putting it in the UI? Is it overwhelming the UI (many Windows controls have scalability problems when they get to thousands of elements)?

Comment: See latest edit - the most expensive thing it's doing is a call to the web.  It takes between 1 and 5 secs, but is stalling the UI while it's there.

Comment: Try this test: change `LoadMyPage` to call `await Task.Run(() => {}).ConfigureAwait(false)` before it calls `RetrieveFeedAsync`. What happens?

Comment: Makes no difference whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your simplified code example, I believe your problem is everything that sits *outside* the await line.

In the following block of code:

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = null;

        SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
        Uri feedUri = new Uri(myUri);

        try
        {
            feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);

            foreach (var item in feed.Items)
            {       
                test.Text += item.Summary.Text + Environment.NewLine;                    
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            test.Text += "Connection failed\n";
        }
    }
```

The *only* line that is executing on a background thread is the line

```
feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);
```

**All** other lines of code in that block are executing on the UI thread.

Just because your button click handler is marked as async doesn't mean code within it doesn't run on the UI thread. In fact the event handler starts ON the UI thread. So, creating the SyndicationClient and setting the Uri happens on the UI thread.

Something many developers don't realize is that any code that comes *after* await will automatically resume on the same thread that was in use *before* the await. This means the code

```
            foreach (var item in feed.Items)
            {       
                test.Text += item.Summary.Text + Environment.NewLine;                    
            }
```

is running on the UI thread!

This is handy in that you don't have to do Dispatcher.Invoke to update **test.Text**, but it also means you're blocking the UI thread the whole time you're looping through items and concatenating strings.

In your (albeit simplified) example, the easiest way to do this work on the background thread would be to have another method on SyndicationClient called **RetrieveFeedAsStringAsync**; Then SyndicationClient can do the download, looping and concatenation of strings all as part of its own task. After that task completes, the only line of code that would run on the UI thread would be assigning the text to the TextBox.

Comment: But I get the same behaviour if I completely remove the `foreach()` loop.